# Influence of LIP on visual cortex

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience

I understand that the lateral intraparietal cortex (LIP) maps [various features of targets](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23473325) onto an [eye-centric reference frame](http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v3/n7/full/nrn873.html). I also know that this mapping predicts where [visual attention (in the form of saccades) will be directed](http://mahoney.cpmc.columbia.edu/goldberglab/goldbergetal2002.pdf) and [helps maintain the integrity of the mapping](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23152627). Finally, I've also noted that the [LIP has various projections to the visual cortex ventral and dorsal stream](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1002072).

What is the function of these projections to the visual cortex? How is the visual cortex influenced by the aforementioned functions of the LIP?

Comment: The LIP could bias neural activity in visual cortex towards more efficiently processing relevant stimuli

Comment: @serk1 I also thought this was likely, but I couldn't find evidence for this hypothesis

Comment: Sabine Kastner (http://www.princeton.edu/~napl/publications.htm) studies this sort of thing and there might be some evidence in one of her papers

Comment: @serk1 a quick search through her titles showed no mention of LIP, but thanks for the link

Comment: You might want to broaden your search to other parietal areas if you're interested in human visual processing